# Does $|A|^{|A|}=2^{|A|}$ hold for any infinite set $A$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Because I know the cardinality of all the functions$f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is $2^{c}$（c is the cardinality of continuum).I wonder whether this holds generally.

Comment: The cardinality of all functions $\{0,1\}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $c^2=c$. The cardinality of all functions from $\mathbb{R}\to \{0,1\}$ is $2^c$. As for what you truly want to ask, the answer is affirmative.

Comment: Yes. And this was asked before, so please search the site before asking.

Comment: @QiyuWen: Nowhere in the question do functions $\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R$ appear. Note that $[0,1]=\{x\in\mathbb R:0\le x\le 1\} \ne \{0,1\}$.

Comment: @celtschk I did notice that, but I considered it a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The axiom of choice implies $\kappa^2=\kappa$ for transfinite cardinals $\kappa$. Then$$2^\kappa\le\kappa^\kappa\le(2^\kappa)^\kappa=2^{\kappa^2}=2^\kappa.$$By the Schröder–Bernstein theorem, we're done.